# Convert WGS-84 encoded string into latitude and longitude using Python

Tags: python, maps, latitude-longitude, wgs84

I'm using [this](https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/doc/route-api) API to get the lat/long points of the route to draw a line following those lat/long points. But the output is an encoded string of WGS-84. 
Example `JSON` output - 
[image]

How to convert this to standard `latitude, longitude` string?

Answer (score 0):

Found an amazing solution - 
[Polyline Library](https://pypi.org/project/polyline/)